# How to send an array of images along with data per image using Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-5, retrofit2, carrierwave

Let's say I have this **model**:

```
data class PhotoRequest(
  @SerializedName("page_number")
  val pageNumber: Int,
  @SerializedName("image")
  val requestBody: MultipartBody.Part
)
```

The **multipart** is created using this:

```
val photo = File(picturePath)
val requestFile = RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),
        photo
    )
return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("images", photo.name, requestFile)
```

The **Retrofit** builder is:

```
 val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder.create()))
```

And this is the **Retrofit** interface:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("my_endpoint")
    fun sendExample(
        @Part("name") name: String,
        @Part("email") email: String,
        @Part("images[]") images: List<PhotoRequest>
    ): Single<String>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to send multiples images along with a param per image, in this case, the number of the page.

The server (rails) is not recognizing the image in any request, in fact, the content inside the key "images" is received as an **array of strings**.

```
 "images"=>["{\"page_number\":1,\"image\":{\"headers\":{\"namesAndValues\":[\"Content-Disposition\",\"form-data; name=\\\"image\\\"; filename=\\\"1537970501549.jpg\\\"\"]]}}}"]
```

Does anyone know how to properly submit this request? or how to manually process the images on the rails side?

Answer (score 3):

That's how you declare in your api interface. You don't need part name for list of images.

```
@Multipart
@POST("my_endpoint")
fun sendExample(
    @Part("name") name: String,
    @Part("email") email: String,
    @Part images: List<MultipartBody.Part>
): Single<String>
```

then wherever you trying to send the request add this method and create list of multipartBody.part

```
 fun prepareFilePart(partName: String, file: File): MultipartBody.Part {
    val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file)
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.name, requestFile)
}

 val listOfImages = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>()
 for (i in 0 until images.size) {
     listOfImages.add(prepareFilePart("image[$i]", images[i]))
 }
```

then you can send the request like that:

```
sendExample("some name", "email@ru.org", listOfImages)
```

Comment: Glad I helped:)

Answer (score 0):

Opening an Gallery intent for multiple images

```rb
public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
  Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  galleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
  startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
}
```

On receiving the result of Gallery intent for multiple images

```rb
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    Uri uri = null;
    //**if Data have multiple images **
    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
      for (int index = 0; index < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); index++) {
        // Getting the URIs of the selected files and logging them into logcat at debug level
        uri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(index).getUri();
        Log.e("mutlifilesUri [" + uri + "] : ", String.valueOf(uri));
        file = new File(new FileUtils(getContext()).getPath(fileUri));
        arrayList.add(fileUri);
      }
    } else {
      uri = data.getData();
      file = new File(new FileUtils(getContext()).getPath(fileUri));
      arrayList.add(fileUri); //add the Uri in a array list
    }
  }
}
```

Convert multiple images into multipartBody for send into service side

```rb
public List < MultipartBody.Part > getMultiAttachment() {
  if (arrayList != null) {
    // create part for file (photo, video, ...)
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
      parts.add(prepareFilePart("multifileAttachment[" + i + "]", arrayList.get(i)));
    }
  }
  return parts;
}

@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {
  // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri

  File file = new File(new FileUtils(getContext()).getPath(fileUri));
  // create RequestBody instance from file
  RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
  // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
  return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}

@Multipart
@POST("api_end_point")
Call < ApiResponse > hitEmailApi(@Part List < MultipartBody.Part > getMultiAttachment());
```